Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6:SIGABRT) with Tensorflow on Mac M1
I am currently trying to run Tensorflow on a Mac with M1 chip and the program keeps constantly aborting when training the model.
The code I have tried is here:
import numpy as np
import scipy.io as spio
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam

# Load D1 dataset
data = spio.loadmat('datasets/data1.mat', squeeze_me=True)
d = data['d']  # Raw signal
Index = data['Index']  # Spike locations (sample indices)
Class = data['Class']  # Spike classes


# Extract spike segments
def extract_spikes(signal, indices, classes, window_size=50):
    spikes = []
    labels = []
    for i, idx in enumerate(indices):
        start = max(0, idx - window_size // 2)
        end = min(len(signal), idx + window_size // 2)
        segment = signal[start:end]
        if len(segment) == window_size:  # Ensure consistent segment size
            spikes.append(segment)
            labels.append(classes[i])
    return np.array(spikes), np.array(labels)

# Parameters
window_size = 50  # Number of samples per spike segment

# Extract data
spike_segments, spike_labels = extract_spikes(d, Index, Class, window_size)

# Normalize data
spike_segments = (spike_segments - np.mean(spike_segments, axis=1, keepdims=True)) / np.std(spike_segments, axis=1, keepdims=True)

# One-hot encode labels for TensorFlow
spike_labels_onehot = to_categorical(spike_labels - 1, num_classes=5)  # Classes are 1–5, convert to 0–4 for indexing

# Split into training and validation sets
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(spike_segments, spike_labels_onehot, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Reshape for TensorFlow (add channel dimension)
X_train = X_train[..., np.newaxis]
X_val = X_val[..., np.newaxis]


# Define CNN model
def build_cnn(window_size):
    model = Sequential([
        Conv1D(16, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', input_shape=(window_size, 1), padding='same'),
        MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2),
        Conv1D(32, kernel_size=5, activation='relu', padding='same'),
        MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        Dropout(0.5),  # Regularization
        Dense(5, activation='softmax')  # 5 classes (softmax for multi-class classification)
    ])
    return model


# Build model
model = build_cnn(window_size)

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
history = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                    validation_data=(X_val, y_val),
                    epochs=10,
                    batch_size=16,
                    verbose=1)

The code seems to crash at the model.fit line when training begins.
This is what the runtime terminal produces, any ideas on how to fix this?
2024-12-03 12:30:31.590013: I metal_plugin/src/device/metal_device.cc:1154] Metal device set to: Apple M1
2024-12-03 12:30:31.590039: I metal_plugin/src/device/metal_device.cc:296] systemMemory: 8.00 GB
2024-12-03 12:30:31.590044: I metal_plugin/src/device/metal_device.cc:313] maxCacheSize: 2.67 GB
2024-12-03 12:30:31.590348: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:306] Could not identify NUMA node of platform GPU ID 0, defaulting to 0. Your kernel may not have been built with NUMA support.
2024-12-03 12:30:31.590590: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/pluggable_device/pluggable_device_factory.cc:272] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 0 MB memory) -> physical PluggableDevice (device: 0, name: METAL, pci bus id: )
Epoch 1/10
2024-12-03 12:30:32.043363: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:117] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6:SIGABRT)
